# Javascript replace function not replacing all

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the following code using the javascript replace but not all instances are being replaced:

```js
var str = '9c88a4f84d6b0c94-3e8a-ca0a320c6509';
str = str.replace("-", ""); 
alert(str);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's replacing the *first* one. That's what it does when you give it a string. To replace all of them, use a regular expression with the `g` flag:

```
str = str.replace(/-/g, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply